# Dois parâmetros com String.Format em um asp:HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net

Gostaria de enviar os parâmetros (ID do database, ClientID) em um `<asp:Hyperlink`. Queria que o resultado final fosse:

```
<a id="ctl00" onclick="OpenModal(704520,'asdf_ID_DaImageAbaixo')">
    <img id="ID_IMAGE" src="../online/img_admin/icon_hist.gif" />
</a>
```

Porém não consigo em 2 coisas. Primeiro as aspas simples não está dando certo.

```
String.Format("AbreModal({0},'{1}')",
```

Dá *Tag não formatada* com essas aspas simples. Sem elas funciona, mas daí não fecha no JavaScript.

Segundo: não consigo capturar a ID da imagem abaixo e enviar nesse link, estou tentando:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" onclick='<%# String.Format("AbreModal({0},{1})", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid"),"123" ) %>'>
 <asp:Image ID="img_Historico" runat="server" ImageUrl="../online/img_admin/icon_hist_off.png" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Como enviar?

Comment: Alguma sugestão pessoal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta algo assim:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" onclick="<%# String.Format("AbreModal({0},\"{1}\"",val1,val2) %>">
   <asp:Image ID="img_Historico" runat="server" ImageUrl="../online/img_admin/icon_hist_off.png" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Substituindo o val1 pelo seu DataBind e o val2 pelo valor do ID

Comment: Não deu certo, com o seu código o resultado foi: `onclick="AbreModal(704520,&quot;123&quot;)` e o detalhe mais importante é que Não consigo passar o `ClientID` da imagem que esta abaixo desse `String.Format`;

Answer (score -2):

Já tentou?

```
onclick='AbreModal(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid")%>, "123" )'
```

Comment: ?? a pergunta é como enviar no lugar do 123 que vc colocou o ID de uma image abaixo ? ele não recupera com ClientID, já tentei por propriedade e tb não deu..